# how to click button javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, cefsharp

I would like to be able to click this. I'm coding in c# and I'm using cefsharp embedded firefox. I came across the code below and I would like to click it if I can. For reference here is the definition for the ExecuteScriptAsync.

```
public void ExecuteScriptAsync(string script);
```

This lets me write javascript. In conjunction with the browser after it visits a webpage. For instance this lets me fill in an email form and password form and click sign in.

```
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('Email').value=" + '\'' + txtEmail.Text + '\'');   
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('Passwd').value=" + '\'' + txtPassword.Text + '\'');     
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('signIn').click()");
```

The below is what I would like to click if possible.

```
<button class="KjTtD twEJfe uq" title="Call a phone">

    <div class="rYvKwe"></div>

</button>
```

While I can click it with my mouse. To get the above code I used firefox's inspect element Q. I've tried a few different ways of clicking it.

Like below.

```
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$('#button a:eq(1)').click();");
```

and

```
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementByTitle('Call a phone').click()");
```

Is it even possible to click it? If so can somebody point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: why aren't you using a simple onclick?

Comment: These APIs can only be used with F12 developer tools and the Diagnostics Script Engine, and can't be called from JavaScript. http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/dn312047

Comment: I've used these and they work for things like filling in a form. browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('Email').value=" + '\'' + txtEmail.Text + '\''); browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('Passwd').value=" + '\'' + txtPassword.Text + '\''); browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('signIn').click()");    The javascript code that is behind the executescriptAsync is from the cefsharp embed browser. Not sure if it is the same ExecuteScriptAsync you posted. But he above code does work to fill in forms.

Comment: you should define an id for the button: `<button id="signIn" ...`. Then the original code should work.

Comment: Is there a way to perform a higher level click perhaps? Like calling the click event on the CefSharp object at a particular coordinate?